# How to increase the number of applications shown in the Recent Applications stack on the Dock

Tags: macos, dock

I've enabled the 'Recent Applications' stack to appear in my Dock:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{ "tile-data" = { "list-type" = 1; }; "tile-type" = "recents-tile"; }'
```

Is there any way to increase the number from 10 Recent Applications to 15, or preferably, omit specific applications from being in it?

Comment: How is this question related to the Dock? The title is confusing. I found this question, but had to ask my own: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411278/show-more-than-three-recent-applications-in-dock?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @KlasMellbourn I'm sorry you're confused but it's really not that confusing. The command in the command line example even has the word 'dock' in it. This was how you enabled 'Recent Items' in your dock before Apple added it to the recent OS's as a standard feature. This solution add's a folder to your dock, your question is asking how to show more applications in the dock itself...so they are very different you are correct

Comment: Ok, but considering that showing recent applications in the dock has _become_ a standard feature, don't you think that your title has become confusing? Your context is a special case, only distantly related to the modern concept. You could remove "In Dock" and the answer would still be relevant.

Comment: I couldn’t do that, because recent applications is also in a Finder quick access folder, as this is explicitly about the dock. You can also do it in a smart folder. And the title is relevant to the intent of usage. You’ve linked your question for your particular issue and I think that would help others with that specific issue.

Comment: @Klas Mellbourn, You should probably keep in mind that this question was asked five years ago, long before **Apple** added the **Show recent applications in Dock** _preference_. That said, I've edited the question so the title is more technically accurate as well changing the term 'folder' to 'stack' as that's the name **Apple** calls this feature. See [Organize files in stacks on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/organize-your-desktop-with-stacks-mh35846/mac) as the technical reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to System Preferences > General > drop down box for recent documents, apps, and servers should do the trick.

Comment: This works, but only after a killall to finder or maybe dock, didn't try dock, but I had to kill finder and relaunch for it to reload, but thanks, I didn't even think to look there

Comment: Can be hard to find the right setting sometimes, especially when doing stuff Cook and his buddies don't want you to do. The easiest way to hide something, is to make it obvious.

Comment: This does not work on Big Sur.