# Show more than three recent applications in Dock

Tags: macos, dock

By default MacOS has `Show recent applications in Dock` enabled. But the Dock only shows the three most recent applications. How can I make the Dock show more than three?

[image: Dock showing the three most recently executed applications]

Note: I know that if you have more than three applications *open* it shows all of them. I am interested in showing more than three even if they are not currently running.

Also note: I am not talking about the setting `System Preferences` > `General` > drop down box for `Recent items`, which is 10 by default and has little to do with the Dock (so this question is *not* a duplicate of [How to increase the number of applications shown in the Recent Applications stack on the Dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170099/increase-number-of-recent-applications-in-dock))

Bonus: ideally I would like to configure this from the command line rather than the GUI.

Comment: No, `Show recent applications` has a specific meaning in `Preferences`, and that is what I want. I don't want to have to click on something to expand the recent applications, I want them immediately visible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was looking for this myself. It took some digging and experimenting, but I figured it out.

You need to add two keys to your com.apple.dock.plist: show-recents and show-recent-count. Adding show-recent-count alone won't work, even if it's enabled in preferences.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock show-recents -bool true;
defaults write com.apple.dock show-recent-count -int 10;
killall Dock
```

And the results:

[image: dock]

Cheers!

Comment: I liked the vertical line that shows up when you have "Show recent applications in Dock" enabled, but I didn't actually want the icons sticking around after closing. I thought it would be cool to try `show-recent-count -int 0`, but it turns out that means "unlimited" and not actually 0. Oh well, thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @Alexander that's why I did this as well, and it works for me. `show-recent-count -int 0` appears not to be showing any recent apps, and I still get the nice vertical bar. I'm on Monterey 12.6.

Comment: Never mind, I don't know exactly what setting the count to `0` does. Whatever integer I set, the behaviour is inconsistent and buggy.

Answer (score 0):

No need to buy a 3rd party app. You can do ist easily yourself in Finder:

Steps 1 and 2 to here, make a Search. Don´t forget to mark "this Mac":
[image]

Step 3 save the Search:
[image]

Look at this Result
[image]

Step 4.1 A few Explanations. Right clicking the new item in the sidebar leads to the containing folder!
[image]

This is the file which represents the search.
[image]

And is finally your new search sitting in the dock:
[image]

Settings in the Dock:

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent sequence of tips. I’ll use this since I don’t have a lot of dock space but love Smart Folders.

Comment: The problem is Dock does update the content intermittent. Sometimes I have to kill Dock to get the latest apps.